# Python Popen _with_ realtime input/output control

Tags: python

I have searched and experimented for over an hour on this and there doesn't seem to be a way to both do a 'here document' and get the output line by line as it occurs:

```
python = '''var="some character text"
print(var)
print(var)
exit()
 '''

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import shlex

def run_process(command):
  p = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  p.stdin.write(python)
  while True:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    if output == '' and p.poll() is not None:
      break
    if output:
      print output.strip()
  rc=p.poll()
  return rc

run_process("/usr/bin/python")
```

The above code hangs indefinitely.  Yes, it's a snake eating its tail, but it was just to prove the concept.

The problem is my subprocess takes a LONG time to run and I need to be able to see the output without waiting hours to figure out if anything is wrong.  Any hints?  Thanks.

Comment: are you sure its `stdin.readline` and not the otherway around

Comment: ``process.poll()`` ought to be an error (in two places) - you have no variable by that name.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  There is a p.stdin.write() call and a p.stdout.readline() call, but no stdin.readline() in the code posted.  Also, I don't have process.poll() - I have an object p with a poll() method.

Comment: I now see what you mean.  Yes - there were some bugs in the example because of some copy/paste issues.  After I implemented the suggestions below in the answer, those turned into raised exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python interpreter behaves differently when run in interactive vs. non-interactive mode. From the [`python(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/python-minimal/python.1.en.html) manual page:

> In non-interactive mode, the entire input is parsed before it is executed.

Of course, “entire input” is delimited by EOF, and your program never sends an EOF, which is why it hangs.

Python runs in interactive mode if its stdin [is a tty](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/manpages-dev/isatty.3.en.html). You can use the [Ptyprocess](http://ptyprocess.readthedocs.io/) library to spawn a process with a tty as stdin. Or use the [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/) library (based on Ptyprocess), which even includes [ready-made REPL wrappers](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/replwrap.html) for Python and other programs.

---

But if you replace Python with sed — which of course doesn’t have an interactive mode — the program still doesn’t work:

```
sed = '''this is a foo!\n
another foo!\n
 '''

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import shlex

def run_process(command):
  p = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  p.stdin.write(sed)
  while True:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    if output == '' and p.poll() is not None:
      break
    if output:
      print output.strip()
  rc=p.poll()
  return rc

run_process("/bin/sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'")
```

This is caused by a different problem: output buffering in sed. Some programs have options to disable buffering. In particular, both sed and Python have a `-u` option, which solves this problem:

```
run_process("/bin/sed -ue 's/foo/bar/g'")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I will retest with `cat` tomorrow to see if it behaves differently.

Comment: This resolved my issue.  If I call p.stdin.close() after p.stdin.write(), this now behaves as expected.  Thanks.